# Is there a way to use redirect window.location.href on multilingual site?

Tags: javascript, redirect, href, window.location

I am trying to add a redirect on a page using JavaScript's `window.location.href`. 
My site is multilingual, and I cannot figure out how to make the URL dynamic so that it redirects to a different language version of the page depending on what language the user is on.

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = "/example"
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **window.navigator.language** to determine user's language preference (based on browser's settings). So the simplest approach would be to do it like this:

```
setTimeout(() => location.href = `/${navigator.language}/example`, 1000); // eg. /en-US/example
```

I used **ES6 template string** to make the url dynamic.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! However, my slugs are all different depending on language so the "/example" would be something different in another language. I tried this code you have kindly provided, however it still redirects me to english version...